# Ngx-datatable - Create mosaic

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I'm using ngx-datatable in my project and I need to create a camera mosaic, but I need to separate columns and rows.

Ex:

My data

```js
    [
      {
        name: "Pet shop",
        id: "1",
        video: 'https://'
      },
      {
        name: "E-shop",
        id: "2",
        video: 'https://'
      },
      {
        name: "My house",
        id: "3",
        url: 'https://'
      },
      {
        name: "Garage",
        id: "4",
        url: 'https://'
      },
    ]
```

What I need

[image]

I would need pagination too.

---

I tried to add dynamic properties to objects to fit the columns

```js
 columnns = [
  { prop: 'column1', name: 'column1' },
  { prop: 'column2', name: 'column2' }
 ]

 myData = [
  {
    name: "Pet shop",
    id: "1",
    video: 'https://',
    column1: 'column1'
  },
  {
    name: "E-shop",
    id: "2",
    video: 'https://',
    column2: 'column2'
   }
 ]
```

---

I tried to join two objects in one too

```js
 columnns = [
  { prop: 'column1', name: 'column1' },
  { prop: 'column2', name: 'column2' }
 ]

myData = [
  {
    column1: "column1",
    camera1: {
      name: "Pet shop",
      id: "5f365ab58a5da52c461c838e",
      video: 'https://',
    },
    column2: "column2",
    camera2: {
      name: "Sala de Espera",
      id: "5f4798948a5da5023294ddb7",
      video: 'https://',
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to bind an object property to the column, but it is only inline. I tried to join the objects into one and make pairs.

Comment: Please post some code showing what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi I posted what I did